# JFrame opens in Server Machine instead of Client

Tags: java, swing, applet, jframe

We are using `JFrame` in our Application to communicate with Signature Pad.
We are done with the implementation of it.

When we are trying to test ,after deploying to QA Server, we came to know that, the frame pop up which is used to capture signature always opens up in the server machine.

Could anyone help us how to make it open on that particular client browser.

Comment: `JFrame` in a browser!!!! Please explain a bit more. Elaborate it with more detailed input. I never downvoted :-)

Comment: Yeah Ok,May be my input would be confusing you.Let me explain you.

Comment: Deploy to testers using [tag:java-web-start].

Answer (score 1):

> Could anyone help us how to make it open on that particular client browser

1. (Convert the frame to a..) `JApplet`
2. Launch the frame from a link using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

As either a developer *or* user, I'd opt for the 2nd.

Comment: Hi,Can you please share me the sample code base and steps for webstart.Am totally new for it.

Comment: The best links I could come up with, I put in the [Java Web Start info.](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) page linked above!  (And again in this comment..)  Let me know if any of the links are out of date, I can hunt down new addresses and update it.